# Calling paint event in another event

Tags: c#, events, timer, invalidation, paintevent

I'm working on snake game, but I got a problem in updating the score!

I have a main area in the form that player can move in it, this area have a paint event that invalidate. I want to show the score out of this area so I add a new paint event on my main form that draws the score on top of the form.

My problem is how can I call second paint event in timer event called update?

second paint event:

```
private void Form1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        Graphics g = e.Graphics;
        Font drawfont = new Font("Arial", 16);
        PointF drawpoint = new PointF(13, 12);
        g.DrawString("Score: "+score.ToString(), drawfont, Brushes.RoyalBlue, drawpoint);


    }
```

Comment: Never call a Paint event directly.  Use this.Invalidate() instead.

Comment: You should also be aware that paint is called quite often. Don't forget to free created resources (Font, Brush, Bitmap,...) when you don't need them anymore. Or better if they don't change as your drawFont create them outside the paint event and dispose them when your form gets disposed.

Comment: yeah,i test the invalidate idea but the form refresh many times that the main area of game can't be shown!